# Sharing common script functions with maven-rpm-plugin

Tags: maven, rpm

I have two separate projects that are built into RPMs using the maven-rpm-plugin.

Both packages have a postinstall script, which contains some duplicated code.

I would like to move the duplicated code into a single 'functions' script that could be inherited by both packages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the common script as a standalone *.sh shell script that is installed and invoked in %post (or any other rpm scriptlet).

Remove the duplication of code by adding a dependency on whatever package you choose to install the common script (but avoiding dependency loops).

Comment: You can do the same with shell functions: use a path to source function definitions from, add a dependency to ensure that the package that includes the common shell function code is installed first, and source the shell function definitions from the path you choose.